# Why Arduino IDE is brignging wrong board name for ESP32 S3

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, esp32-s3

[image]

I am designing a pcb for ESP32 S3 wroom-1 for testing pins which are safe to use.

My PCB look like this:

[image]

I program ESP32 S3 via USB interface gpio19 "D-" gpio20 "D+". When I plug in my usb, Arduino ide brings wrong name for my Esp32 board. By the way I use USB TYPE C. Everyday it gives different names. Correct one is "ESP32S3 DEV MODULE".

**How can I set it to select the correct module automatically on Arduino Ide** as ESP32S3 Dev Module?

WRONG 1

[image]

WRONG 2

[image]

WRONG 3

[image]

same board different names. interesting

Comment: I've noticed that some ESP32 boards have a USB-to-Serial chip that is programmed with a confusing (i.e. wrong) identifier. There's no way to change this, but it will not have any effect on the board's functionality as long as you select the right board when you're programming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an Arduino IDE update 2.2, something was solved, yesterday (30,08,2023).

There is a new edit button appearing on the board selection menu and then Arduino ide recognises esp32 even after plugging out and in again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just force Arduino IDE to recognise your board by locating your *Boards Configuration File*, putting in your VID and PID values, repackage and host the configurations and Point the Arduino IDE to your custom board manager URL.

On my MacBook device I have used `ioreg -p IOUSB -l` after plugging in a device and copy the idVendor, idProduct properties. These are the VID and PID values. On Windows you may open Device Manager, look under the Ports (COM & LPT), right click on your board (it might appear as a COM port) and choose "properties", go to "details" menu, and there from the dropdown menu, select "Hardware Ids". you should see values like VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY. these are your VID and PID. on Linux you may just use "lsusb" and find the vendor ID and PID there.

After finding those you must go to ESP32 board package directory and find boards.txt (https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/boards.txt). Find the line that starts with `esp32s3.name=ESP32S3 Dev Module`. There you must modify the PID and VID values with your actual VID and PID values that you collected as mentioned above. Replace `0xXXXX` with your VID and `0xYYYY` with your PID.

After modifying, you'll need to compress the entire board package directory into a ZIP archive. Make sure the directory structure remains intact so that the Arduino IDE can recognize and install it correctly.

Then you can create a new repository on GitHub, upload the ZIP archive to this repository, then click on the ZIP file inside the repository, then click the "Download" button. Copy the link.

Now you must go to the Arduino IDE, go to `file` -> `preferences`. in the "Additional Boards Manager URLs" field, click on the icon on the right to open a window where you can insert new lines. Add the direct link to your ZIP file and click OK. Go to Tools -> Board -> Boards Manager. then search for ESP32. your custom package should appear in the list. Click "Install". after it installs you are good to go.

**VERY IMPORTANT EDIT**: after investigating this issue a little more I have came to realisation that so called "random board names" that show up all have the same VID and PID values. The problem was not the incorrect VID and PID values for your board, **the problem was that a bunch of other boards also have the same VID and PID values**. A simple yet effective fix would be to assign random names to all the other ones than the one you want to use. Just edit the

```
adafruit_qtpy_esp32c3.vid.0=0x303a

adafruit_qtpy_esp32c3.pid.0=0x1001
```

lines for every board other than what you want to use. But never forget to change this text file if you ever start doing long-run development with one of the other boards. Or the other boards (such as u-blox NORA-W10 s3" won't be auto detected.

Comment: A comprehensive explanation of this also appears here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-nano-esp32-board-is-always-identified-as-adafruit-esp32/1241431/2